How to calculate date diff in the below scenario using databricks sql?
Input -

I want to derive a column based on below steps -

Check for same ServiceId and Name but Ref is different.
If so, then calculate day diff like below -


(take ActualEndTime from 1st row and CreatedDate from 2nd row if ServiceId and Name are matched for diff Ref)

Then derive a column 'Flag' based on DayDiff calculated in step 2.
If DayDiff is greater than 30, then Flag should be 0 else 1


(take ActualEndTime from 1st row and CreatedDate from 2nd row if ServiceId and Name are matched for diff Ref)
